# MonetDB - left/right joins too slow than inner join

Tags: join, left-join, database-performance, monetdb

I have been comparing MySQL with MonetDB. Obviously, queries that took minutes in MySQL got executed in a matter of few seconds in Monet.

However, I found a real blockade with joins.

I have 2 tables - each with 150 columns. Among these (150+150) columns, around 60 are CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT type. Both the tables are populated with around 50,000 rows - with data in all the 150 columns. The average length of data in a CLOB type column is 9,000 (varying from 2 characters to 20,000 characters). The primary key of both the tables have same values and the join is always based on the primary key. The rows are by default inserted in ascending order on the primary key.

When I ran **an inner join query on these two tables with about 5 criteria and with limit 1000, Monet processed this query in 5 seconds**, which is completely impressive compared to MySQL's (19 seconds).

But when I ran **the same query with same criteria and limits using a left or right joins, Monet took around 5 minutes, which is clearly way behind MySQL's (just 22 seconds)**.

I went through the logs using trace statement, but the traces of inner and left joins are more or less the same, except that time for each action is far higher in left join trace.

Also, the time taken for the same join query execution varies by 2 or 3 seconds when run at several time intervals.

Having read a lot about Monet's speed compared to traditional relation row based DBs, I could feel that I am missing something, but couldn't figure out what.

Can anyone please tell me why there is such a huge difference in such query execution time and how I can prevent it?

Much grateful to have any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S.: I am running Monet on Macbook Pro - 2.3 GHz Core i7 - Quad core processor with 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Can you share your dataset and queries please? It's difficult to tell what is going on otherwise. Generally, are you selecting all the columns in the result?